# How to link to -llapack when compiling fortran using gfortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran, lapack

I am trying to compile a simple program, example.f90

```
program example

use dsyevd

implicit none

end program example
```

I am compiling using the command

```
gfortran -llapack example.f90
```

However this compilation returns the message

```
Fatal Error: Cannot open module file 'dsyevd.mod' for reading at (1): No such file or directory
```

dsyevd is a function in lapack. I have installed intel-mkl onto my computer which contains lapack95. Any advice on how to link my compile to these libraries would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Direct your favourite search engine towards *Intel link line adviser*.

Comment: What is your Fortran program trying to achieve?

Comment: The actual problem is for Hamiltonian matrix construction and diagnolisation. The program in my question is just a toy program to replicate the issue.

Comment: What I am confused about is why you think there is a module called dsyevd. Does your program contain such a module? Or are you trying to call the lapack routine? Note the error message as reported has nothing to do with the lapack library - that would be a link time error, while the above is at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Lapack does not contain any module called `dsyevd`, so you cannot `use` it. It is a [subroutine](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d2/d8a/group__double_s_yeigen_ga77dfa610458b6c9bd7db52533bfd53a1.html) so it should be `call`ed.

Using `-llapack` is OK for the default Lapack pre-installed in your Linux distribution. For MKL you must use the appropriate options from the [Link Advisor](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/intel-mkl-link-line-advisor.html).